# regression model in R use dummy cols

Tags: r, linear-regression

i want to build a regression model.
i have data about job sekeers, academics, non-academics, woman and man.
the data seperated to areas (7).
i try to type this code but im not sure that it is the right model for my data...
I would be happy to help with this.

cleanData - the csv file, contains data from 01/2010 - 04/2020
I deleted the columns of month, city and the name of the city

```
regressionSubset <- cleanData  
regressionSubset$MONTH <- NULL
regressionSubset$CITY <- NULL
regressionSubset$LOCALITY.NAME <- NULL

regressionData <- dummy_cols(regressionSubset, remove_first_dummy = TRUE, remove_selected_columns = TRUE)  
regressionData <- data.frame(scale(regressionData))
set.seed(42)
model <- lm(ESTIMATED.CITY.UNEMPLOYMENT ~ ., data = regressionData)
step_model <- stepAIC(model, trace = FALSE)
summary(step_model)
extract_eq(step_model, use_coefs = TRUE, wrap=TRUE, terms_per_line = 1)
```